# I am facing issue while using subprocess.Popen in Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

My requirement is, I am calling a shell script from my python script. When the python script is executed. It shows all the shell script content(not only the echo, even the secret keys which are read from param files in shell script) in the output.
Here is my code

```
bashCommand = "sh -x {0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} ".format(Shell_script, local_directory,dest_file_path,Overwrite_Flag,file_name,client_id, tenant_id, encrypt_location)
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()
logger.info(output.decode())
```

I just have to write the output of the shell into a log file and if possible I have to print the output of the shell script but not the entire content of the shell script.

Kindly help on this,
Thanks

Comment: Use subprocess.run()

Comment: If you don't want to see the commands being run, why are you invoking `sh` with the `-x` option?  That's exactly what that option does.

Comment: Why are you building a string only to split it again? `Popen(["sh", "-x", Shell_script, local_directory, dest_file, ...])`.

Comment: The tracing messages due to `-x` are written to `stderr`, not `stdout`. Since you're only redirecting `stdout` to the pipe, the trace messages get written to the terminal.

Comment: @chepner your solution also worked for me. Thank you